# How to make a very long non-stop string (without any space in it) break into many new lines when showing in HTMLPanel?

Tags: gwt

I have an HTMLPanel inside a FlowPanel which is inside a ScrollPanel like this.

```
<g:ScrollPanel> 
    <g:FlowPanel>
        <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="showMessageHTMLPanel" width="600px"/>
    </g:FlowPanel>
</g:ScrollPanel>
```

The `showMessageHTMLPanel` is used to hold the text that user enter a `TextArea`.

I want that the `showMessageHTMLPanel` should show exactly like how it was displayed in `TextArea`.

Ex,if user types in many sentences in new lines in `TextArea`, then the `showMessageHTMLPanel` should show similar like this:

```
This is text1

This is text2.
```

So here is what I did. I uses `new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscapedLines(message).toSafeHtml()`.

```
HTML showMessageHTML = new HTML(new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscapedLines(message).toSafeHtml());
getView().getShowMessageHTMLPanel().add(showMessageHTML);
```

The result is that It breaks the lines quite OK, no problem.

However, When I type a non-stop very long string ( a String that doesn't have any space on it) into a TextArea. Ex, see this non-stop string:

"Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa."

As you saw, even this non-stop string has no space, but when typing in `TextArea` then the string will automatically fall into new lines.

Ok, now when I show that non-stop string in `getView().getShowMessageHTMLPanel()`, it showed the text as one straight line without any line break:

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
```

The user has to scroll the scrollbar to see the complete text. This is unacceptable since it is too hard to see the whole line. Also many urls are non-stop string without spaces. So the user may not be able to copy the url.

**How to make a very long non-stop string (without any space in it) break into many new lines when showing in HTMLPanel?**

Or

**Do you know any other widget that can handle this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure, a simple css property should help.

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

[Detail here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: Work like charm. Thank you very much.